# PHP - Insert date to url

Tags: php

i have a contact form and after user submit the form i want it to redirect to our promotion page, i know how to do redirect after form submission but i need to insert date(month/dd/yyyy) to url automatically like: http://myshop.com/promotion/index.php?from=September/dateoftomorrow/2014&to=September/dateaftertomorrow/2014

Is it possible to do it using php ? if yes could you guide me how to do that please?
Many thanks :)

Comment: Yes you can. Please read the php doc about making a redirect, and try. Please put some effort in research before you ask. Read the Stack overflow FAQ on asking questions.

Comment: It's difficult to answer this in a way that will be useful to you - let alone future readers - because it's unclear where your problem is. You say you know how to perform redirects, so which step *don't* you know how to do? Getting tomorrow's date? Formatting it the way you need? Inserting it into the URL you want to redirect to? As soon as you clarify exactly what you need, chances are there'll be an easily-findable duplicate on SO describing exactly how to perform that step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need something like this:

```
<?php

// get the timestamp of tomorrow
$tomorrow = strtotime('+ 1 day');

// get the timestamp of the day after tomorrow
$after_tomorrow = strtotime('+ 2 day');

// the format we build the date in
$format = 'F/d/Y';

// get the tomorrow date in the specified format
$from = date($format, $tomorrow);

// get the day after tomorrow date in the specified format
$to = date($format, $after_tomorrow);

// build the URL
$url = 'http://myshop.com/promotion/index.php';
$url .= '?from=' . $from;
$url .= '&to=' . $to;

// redirect to the URL
header("Location: " . $url);
exit;

?>
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Feel free to upvote my answer if you find it helpful. I'm wondering who downvoted my answer, as it is exactly what you needed, and it is working. I would appreciate if the downvoter posts here the reason for downvoting my answer.

Comment: i'm really sorry that i don't have enough reputation to upvote the answer. really sorry about that :(

Comment: I agree @MarinAtanasov ... It really bothers me when users don't mention when and why they down vote. IMO, this should be a requirement for these boards. It would discourage flagrant down voting.

Answer (score 1):

In order to pass the date to the next page. Convert the date to the equivalent time stamp using the strtotime() function.

```
$url = "http://myshop.com/promotion/index.php?from=".strtotime('September/dateoftomorrow/2014')."&to=".strtotime('September/dateaftertomorrow/2014')
```

If you need the date in the URL try encoding date in URL using the urlencode() function

```
$url = "http://myshop.com/promotion/index.php?from=".urlencode('September/dateoftomorrow/2014')."&to=".urlencode('September/dateaftertomorrow/2014')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write
header("Location:http://redirect-name.com?to=" . $mm . "/" . $dd . "/" . $yy);

Maybe in your case you will need to use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] if you want to reuse the current path